# jquery: function runs automatically whenever the page loads?

Tags: jquery, onclick, bootstrap-modal

When I load up my .jsp page, the secondFunction() runs automatically (which pops up a modal whenever I load the page). Even though I have used the *callback()* property, to enable secondFunction() to run only if firstFunction() has finished up, it automatically runs every time I load the page. I only want it to run when I press the button, and when the firstFunction() has finished up. Any ideas?

HTML code:

```
<a class="open-buttonedModal icon-info-sign"  onclick="firstFunction()"></a>
```

Jquery:

```
        function firstFunction(callback) {
            $('td').click(function() {

                var emp = $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();
                var url = "timesheet.jsp?ename=" + emp;
                $(location).attr('href', url);

            });

            callback();

        }
        function secondFunction() {

            $('#buttonedModal').modal('show');

        }

        firstFunction(function() {
            secondFunction();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.click()` function only *binds* an event handler, doesn't wait for it to actually be run. You should place your `callback()` at the end of the event handler:

```
    function firstFunction(callback) {
        $('td').click(function() {
            // ... other clicky stuff

            callback();
        });

    }
```

---

To only run it *once*, both after the page loads up, and after the button has been clicked, use a separate event handler with `.one()`:

```
   function firstFunction(callback) {
        $('td').click(function() {
            // ... other clicky stuff
        }).one('click', function() {
            callback(); // can also be used without the function() {} wrapper
        });

    }
```

---

Also, to avoid undecipherable error messages in the future, you can check that `callback` is indeed a function before you try running it:

```
 if(typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback();
 } else {
      console.log('callback is not a function'); // possibly throw an error, too?
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code. Now modal doesn't pop-up initially when the page loads, but it has stopped appearing when the button in clicked. The screen goes dark like its going to appear, but it goes back to normal and no thing happens.

Comment: Well the modal/click functionality is not wrong, assuming that you *never* click on the `icon-info-sign` (you should probably remove that entirely) and that the `location.href` switch is not messing it up. I'd look for the problem elsewhere. If you reproduce your issue in eg. [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) could probably be of more help